# Create html table in jQuery from array

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, post

I have an array of elements from my database. I used ajax (POST procedure) to get it. Now I want to create a table, which will contain those elements. I don't exactly know how to do it in jQuery. I've got this:

```
$.post('script.php',{login: '1'}, 'json').done(function(data) { 
    results = ''; 
    data.table.forEach(function(row){
        results += '<tr><td>' + row.name + '</td><td>' + row.lastname + '</td><td>' + row.data + '</td></tr>';
    });
    $('#MyTable tbody').html(results);
});
```

My script look's like:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
...
$result=mysql_query($query); 
$table = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$table[] = $row;
}
$data['table'] = $table;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Edit:
I corrected my mistakes and Now I have errors in console when I open table. It displays:

```
TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
```

Does somebody know how the structure of this sentence should look ?

Comment: And what isn't working ?

Comment: Well, nothing is displayed... I'm not sure what's wrong. My array from script is like:  Array ( [0] => 2 [id] => 2 [1] => Roberto [name] => Roberto [2] => Robertos [lastname] => Robertos [3] => 2016-01-27 22:10:18 [data] => 2016-01-27 22:10:18 )

Comment: doesn't seem to be a property `table` in that array. try just `data.forEach(..`. Sample of whole json structure would help

Comment: check browser console for errors also

Comment: Typo: `row.lastanme` should be `row.lastname`. But that won't cause this problem.

Comment: I added my script structure. No it's not. There are no errors in console. Also delete property 'table' doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you said your php script has data, so I guess the problem should be
this line:

```
echo json_encode();
```

it should be

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

In your javascript I would do it this way

```
$.post('script.php',{login: '1'}, function(data) { 
results = ''; 
$.each(data.table, function(idx, row){
    results += '<tr><td>' + row.name + '</td><td>' + row.lastanme + '</td><td>' + row.data + '</td></tr>';
});
$('#MyTable tbody').html(results);
```

});

Comment: OMG thanks but it doesn't solve whole problem. Now when I correct my script , when I open table i've got error in console:
TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
Does somebody know how the structure of this should look ?

Comment: Thank You for your help, but still nothing is displayed (but there are no errors in console now)

Comment: well, 2 possible problems here, 
1. you didn't get response from php script, see what you got with console.log(data)

2. if there is response, see what you have with console.log(results)
after the $.each() loop

Comment: OK I SOLVE it. The problem was in names of table... THANK YOU VERY MUCH dude.